# Let $G=<g>$ be a finite cyclic group, and let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of $G$. Prove if |H| divides |K|, then $H\leq K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Here is my attempt:

$H = <g^h> = (g^{nh} | n\in Z)$
and
$K = <g^k> = (g^{nk} | n\in Z)$

We are given that $|H|$ divides $|K|$, so $|K|=p|H|$ for some integer p.

We know that
$|H|=|<g^h>| = \frac{|g|}{gcd(h,|g|)}$
$|K|=|<g^k>| = \frac{|g|}{gcd(k,|g|)}$

So now we can write:

$$|K|=p|H|$$
$$\frac{|g|}{gcd(k,|g|)}=\frac{p|g|}{gcd(h,|g|)}$$
$$gcd(h,|g|) = p(gcd(k,|g|)$$

From here I am stuck. I don't know how to deduce that H is a subgroup of K from this part onward. I am a beginner to proofs involving cyclic subgroups so I feel like I'm on a red herring. I know we can use the finite subgroup test, but I just don't see it with what I have. Some pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I keep your notation. Apparently, you want to use that every subgroup of $G$ is cyclic, which is an excellent idea!  However, one may be a bit more precise :for each positive divisor $d$ of $n=\vert G\vert$, there is a unique subgroup of order $d$, and this subgroup is precisely $\langle g^{\frac{n}{d}}\rangle$.

Now, if $d=\vert H\vert $ and $e=\vert K\vert$, you have $d\mid e$, so $(n/e) \mid (n/d)$, and I am sure that you can see how to conclude now.

PS. If you don't know the result I used on subgroups, I can add a proof if you want. Just let me know...

Comment: $(n/d) | (n/e)$ means $(n/e) = r(n/d)$ for some r. Then you get $d = er$ which implies that $e|d$. But $d|e$, so $d = e$.   Is this right so far?

Comment: sorry, it was a misprint: $n/e\mid n/d$. I'm correcting the type right away...

Comment: I know the result that you used, it is in the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups. I am unsure about what $(n/e) | (n/d)$ implies. I can expand it out and I will get $e = dr$ for some integer r. But this is just $d | e$ which we already knew. I actually used that very same theorem. I stated that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and thus it has its own cyclic subgroup within $G$. And since $|H|$ divides $|K|$, H has its own cyclic subgroup within $K$. So $H \leq K$